# How to select a date range in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to select a portion of my dataframe with dates containing 2022 up to latest date and that may include (today and tomorrow and next). How can I achieve that?

`df= df.filter(col("sales_date").contains("2022"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use between function or even '>'

```
df= df.filter(col("date").between("2022-01-01", "2022-12-31"))
```

or

```
df= df.filter(col("date") > "2022-01-01")
```

Comment: The conversion seems to work. After the run,

I see date: date
which means the format is now 'date'.

However, when I check the the schema with 
df.PrintSchema(), I still see date as  string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned about, 'between' syntax will do the trick, just make sure your column is converted in a proper format: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-convert-string-to-timestamp-format/

Answer (score 0):

you can use **like** in filter where in `%` works as wild card char.

```
scala> var df = Seq(("2022-01-01"),("2021-02-01")).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df = df.withColumn("date",col("value").cast("date"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, date: date]

scala> df.printSchema
root
|-- value: string (nullable = true)
|-- date: date (nullable = true)

scala> df.show()
+----------+----------+
|     value|      date|
+----------+----------+
|2022-01-01|2022-01-01|
|2021-02-01|2021-02-01|
+----------+----------+


scala> df.filter(col("date").like("2022%")).show()
+----------+----------+
|     value|      date|
+----------+----------+
|2022-01-01|2022-01-01|
+----------+----------+
```